# How can i change expiry_in parameter of token in oauth2 with django rest

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

curl
-X POST -d 
"grant_type=password&username=&password=" -u":" 
http://localhost:8000/o/token/

I get the access token:

{ "access_token": "bWT0hgV6nXdvwIXuk7SREtZYWGWJOp",
  "expires_in": 36000,
 "token_type": "Bearer",
 "scope": "read write groups",
 "refresh_token": "5DUMuBWIHdBMFyGDKeJidCR6gD0Ftc" }

I want to change "expires_in" parameter to 2000.

Comment: Please elaborate your question with more information

Answer (score 0):

It seems you generate token in your application. Focus on the method generates token. There should be some setting like

```
payload = {
    "iss": "example.com",
     "iat": int(time.time()),
     "exp": int(time.time()) + 2000,
     "aud": "www.example.com",
     "sub": account['_id'],
     "username": username,
     "scopes": ['open']
}
```

, you just need to set the `exp` 2000s after now.

If you use an third party application, you can try to find configuration about expiration, or lifetime of token. If there's no UI configuration, there should be some configuration files to set this. Even worse, you can try to find `"exp"` in source code and set the value manually.